# Nested list to nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

I have what seems to be a tricky question, but probably quite a simple solution.

I have a nested list that I wish to have the first value of every list contained to be the key within a dictionary. I wish to have every other element contained within that list to be added as a value to that key.

Here is a sample of the nested list:

```
stations[[1, 'carnegie', 12345, 30],[2, 'london', 12344, 30], [4, 'berlin', 1345563, 30]]
```

I wish to convert this to a dictionary in the following format:

```
stations {1:['carnegie', 12345, 30], 2:['london', 12344, 30], 4:['berlin', 1345563, 30]}
```

The nested list is quite large, so I've only included as sample here :)

My current attempts have yielded the best option as:

```
newDict = dict.fromkeys(stations,{})
```

Which gives me:

```
{1: {}, 2:{}, 4:{}}
```

To which I'm at a loss how to combine both the keys and values to make my ideal dictionary.

Any help on this would be great.

**EDIT:**

To add, I'd like to be able to assign a variable name to the dictionary as with the current solution provided below:

```
{i[0] : i[1:] for i in stations}
```

This give me the correct output in a loop, but when I assign a variable to it in the loop it gives me the final key:value in the dictionary

```
newDict = {}
 for y in stations:
   newDict = {y[0] : y[1:]}

print newDict
```

returns:

```
{4: ['berlin', 1345563, 30]}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> stations = [[1, 'carnegie', 12345, 30],[2, 'london', 12344, 30], [4, 'berlin', 1345563, 30]]
```

You can use a `dict` comprehension

```
>>> {i[0] : i[1:] for i in stations}
{1: ['carnegie', 12345, 30], 2: ['london', 12344, 30], 4: ['berlin', 1345563, 30]}
```

Comment: In Python 3, you can use the expanded iterable unpacking syntax to avoid the index and slice, if you want: `{key: value for key, *value in stations}`

Comment: This does the job. However when I attempt to assign the results for that loop to a variable it only gives me the last key and it's elements. ie: `print newDict` returns `{4: ['berlin', 1345563, 30]}` Is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: @BenW the dict-comp is *already* a *loop* - all you're doing in your loop is keep creating a new dictionary with a single entry each turn... Take cyber's code and do: `newDict = {i[0] : i[1:] for i in stations}` - there ya go... all done...

Comment: @JonClements + Cyber: Had a bit of trouble with that in Eclipse. Realised even changing to 2.76 as the interpreter and explicitly stating so in numerous places in Eclipse it just wouldn't work. So I tried a restart and now it's all hunky dory. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @BenW don't forget to accept Cyber's answer if it's worked for you

Answer (score 1):

Use a `dict` comprehension:

```
{i[0]: i[1:] for i in stations}
```