# convert multidimensional list into dictionary python

Tags: python

I'm working on a problem, and it would be much easier to solve if I had an elegant way to convert a multi dimensional list of n elements into a dictionary of keys corresponding with the index and values corresponding with the list values.

Example:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] => {0:[1,2,3], 1:[4,5,6], 2:[7,8,9]}
```

Is there a simple way to do this with Python?

Comment: Yes, `dict` comprehension and `enumerate`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested list to nested dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584025/nested-list-to-nested-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: With `enumerate`, this is easy. Try?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I have a counter question for you to understand the better what you are trying to do. If you want to make dictionary like that and access the elements using key, you could do it from the list too, directly. So what is your final goal here?

Comment: It's ironic you picked the answer that didn't use enumerate

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some steps follow you can convert your any kind of multi dimensional list into dictionary

**Step 1 :** 
call your list :

```
mylist =  [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

**Step 2:** 
stored dict variable name

```
mydict =  {}

for i in range(len(mylist)):
  mydict[i] = mylist[i]

print(mydict)
```

**Result :**

```
{0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 5, 6], 2: [7, 8, 9]}
```

[Note : The result is tested ]

Answer (score 3):

To expand on my comment:

```
>>> array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> {index: list(value) for index, value in enumerate(array)}
{0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 5, 6], 2: [7, 8, 9]}
```

*changed `value` to `list(value)` to avoid byref v. byval issues*

Comment: Careful: you need `index: list(value)` for the assignment if you want an actual copy, not just another reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using enumerate on the list:

```
new_dict = {}
for itr, ele in enumerate(array):
    new_dict[itr] = ele
return new_dict
```

There may be another solution that is a little less code but this should work for what you are trying to do, assuming the index should be the key.

EDIT:

`{itr: ele for itr, ele in enumerate(array)}`